# Shuffle 4 arrays with paired objects, then push it

Tags: javascript

I have 4 arrays which shuffle themselves, works as expected, so far so good.

```
let groupAB = shuffleArray(["A", "B",]); 
let groupCD = shuffleArray(["C", "D",]); 
let groupEF = shuffleArray(["E", "F",]); 
let groupHG = shuffleArray(["G", "H",]);
```

but now i want to shuffle the group arrays and push it to a new existing array.

I tried doing it so:

```
let availablePositions = [];
let groupAB = shuffleArray(["A", "B",]); 
let groupCD = shuffleArray(["C", "D",]); 
let groupEF = shuffleArray(["E", "F",]); 
let groupHG = shuffleArray(["G", "H",]);
let availableGroups = shuffleArray([...groupAB, ...groupCD, ...groupEF, ...groupHG]);
    availablePositions.push(...availableGroups);
```

Which doesnt work as expected. e.g.: "A" "B" get split up and sometimes end up on the other side of the spectrum. To give some visualisation why this needs to be done; I'm making a map for an rts game. "A" to "H" are each a starting position for a player to begin. But i want pairs of people for a 2v2v2v2 scenario. So A and B need to stick together. I'm very noob to JS and its probably an obvious mistake. The script runs without errors.

Comment: The problem is you don't want results like this: `[A, G, H, B]` ?

Comment: Yes, excactly. I need A, B to be together, bot not always the first 2 in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shuffle by groups and flat the array. For example for:

Nodejs11:

```
let availableGroups = shuffleArray([groupAB, groupCD, groupEF, groupHG]);
let availablePositions = availableGroups.flat();
```

For lower versions:

```
let availableGroups = shuffleArray([groupAB, groupCD, groupEF, groupHG]);
availableGroups.forEach((v) => availablePositions.push(...v));
```